# How to run all functions before going to next sequence in loop?

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-asyncio

I don't know if I understood `asyncio` correctly, or if I'm doing something wrong. But I'd like to run all functions for each `app` before the next `app` in the loop get called.

Every function must run in that specific order before going to next `app` in the `cycle`.

My script:

```
# Cycle through the bots in one loop rather than restarting the loop in an infinite loop
for app in cycle(applications):
    print('Going to bot: ' + str(app[1]))
    app[2].set_focus()  
    # Steps of this bot:
    # - Connect
    await asyncio.create_task(connect_wallet(app_name=app[1]))
    # - Login
    await asyncio.create_task(login_metamask(app_name=app[1]))
    # - Treasure Hunt
    await asyncio.create_task(treasure_hunt_game(refresh_only=True, app_name=app[1]))   
    # - New map
    await asyncio.create_task(new_map(app_name=app[1]))
    # - Check for errors
    await asyncio.create_task(skip_error_on_game(app_name=app[1]))
```

How to continue to the next `app` in the `cycle` only after all the functions are completed in the above sequence?

Comment: Beside the point, but you can simplify that print: `print('Going to bot:', app[1])`. `print()` automatically converts it arguments to str.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do nothing else because you used await before every task so it already 'awaits' until the task is done to move to the next line.

Comment: That's strange because the next `app` is being called after some functions finish their work, not after the last function gets called (`skip_error_on_game`), but it's not always in the same spot.

Comment: It doeson't make sense... probably you forgot to await for something inside the `skip_error_on_game` function

Comment: Yes, I agree! Since it's my first time using `asyncio` and `apscheduler`, I might doing something wrong. But you can check in my repo if you want: https://github.com/guimatheus92/Bot_BombCrypto